# Postgres - reference aggregate field alias in subquery

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to access the outer queries alias of parent_id, which is taken from a custom postgres function written to traverse a tree, inside the inner subquery.

```
select 
    i.id,
    unnest(array_agg(traversal.id)) as parent_id,
    (select item_type from items i_2 where i_2.id = parent_id) as item_type
from 
    items i 
cross join 
    link_traversal(start_node, depth) as traversal
where 
    si.id in [ids] and
    item_type in [types]
group by 
    si.id;
```

running the above sql throws the error:

```
column "parent_id" does not exist
```

Comment: parent_id is alias name here. so it can't be used in corelated subquery as a table column.

Comment: @RahulBiswas Is it possible to reference the aggregation inside the subquery? The idea being for every unnested parent_id, I want to find it's correlated item_type in the items table

Comment: please provide sample input with table structure and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use postgres anyway, you don't actually need a stored procedure or some complicated index to retrieve recursive relation. Just use [recursive common table expression](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/recursive-queries-postgresql/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwpf2IBhDkARIsAGVo0D01clFP-PkAgaUrLAo4KtD8CDjNDCGtAXhezF2BPGmVEVegAob_ggcaArXVEALw_wcB)

```
WITH RETURSIVE recurse AS (
    SELECT parent_id, id, 0 AS depth FROM items WHERE id = :start_node_id:

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT i.parent_id, i.id, r.depth + 1 AS depth 
      FROM items i 
      JOIN recurse r 
        ON i.parent_id = r.id
    HAVING depth < :max_depth:
) SELECT i.* FROM recurse r JOIN items i ON i.id = r.id;
```